# Why doesn't my loop trigger inside a function?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm just trying to perform a very simple for loop in a function and yet it's not working as expected. However, If I replace the checkForImage() call with the contents of the function, it works. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
dict := {"img1": "shark","img2": "blue","img3": "red"}

sendAnswers(answer) {
  msgbox, %answer%
}

checkForImage() {
    MsgBox hi
    for key, val in dict
     MsgBox %val%
    return
}

^z::
   checkForImage()
```

I get a message box with "hi" but the loop doesn't seem to do anything.

I am using Version 1.1.30.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. The function simply cannot "see" `dict`. There are a couple of ways to solve this problem, see [Global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Functions.htm#Global).

First method: Only `dict` is global, all other variables are accessible only within `checkForImage()`. If you're accessing only `dict` or a couple more global variables, this method is recommended.

```
checkForImage() {
    global dict ; Only dict will be global (accessible outside this function)
    myLocalVariable := 0 ; This is accessible only within this function

    MsgBox hi
    for key, val in dict
        MsgBox %val%
}
```

Second method: ALL variables within the function is global.

```
checkForImage() {
    Global  ; dict and all other global variables will be accessible

    myNotLocalVariable := 0 ; This is accessible even outside this function
    MsgBox hi
    for key, val in dict
     MsgBox %val%
    return
}
```

Third method: Declare `dict` as a super-global variable.

```
global dict := {"img1": "shark","img2": "blue","img3": "red"}
checkForImage() {
    MsgBox hi
    for key, val in dict
     MsgBox %val%
    return
}
```